# Bose QuietComfort 35 Bluetooth Headphones crackling/choppy when connected to Mac?

Tags: mac, bluetooth, headphones

QC35's are linked to both my iPhone and my Mac but when I connect the headphones to my Mac (without pairing to my iPhone) the sound is choppy (brief & frequent loss in audio).

Sometimes pairing my iPhone fixes the problem but not always. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I no longer experience these issues so it was likely fixed by a previous update. Open the "Bose Connect" app on your phone and make sure your firmware is up to date.

---

When experiencing issues on Mac, open the "Bose Connect" app on your iPhone and connect to your headphones from there (if not already connected).

The app correctly configures the headphones and eliminates all sound issues.

Answer (score 2):

The sound quality of the Bose QC35 when connected to mac depends on the used audio codec. Sadly, mac computers tend to switch to the low-quality SCO codec when a Bluetooth headset is also used as "input device" (microphone).

Active codec can be shown by by ⌥-clicking the Bluetooth icon in the macOS Menu Bar.

[image: screenshot showing active SCO codec]

Current best practice is to set the Internal Microphone of your mac as Input Device, and keep the Bose QC35 only selected as Output Device. Input and Output devices can be selected in System Settings > Sound or by ⌥-clicking the Volume icon in the macOS Menu Bar, and selecting devices there.

When the Bose QC35 is not used as an Input Device, mac audio playback can leverage the higher quality AAC codec:

[image: screenshot showing active AAC codec]

Comment: Hmm I've certainly noticed this loss in audio quality when joining Zoom video meetings, so this could certainly be useful for that. But on my mac, I have my QC35 set as my mic and my codec/sound is AAC/great. I haven't had an issue for as long as I can remember. Is your MacOS fully up to date and did you follow what I outlined in my answer?

Comment: @JBallin I am running the latest version of macOS and latest firmware update of QC35. Your proposed solution (Opening the Bose Connect app on my iPhone and connecting to the QC35) does not solve the problem for me; only the solution I wrote here seems to fix the problem for me.

Comment: Interesting! Appreciate you sharing. Learned about the detail view in Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

My headphones were also skipping occasionally dropping a few milliseconds that was barely noticeable, but drove me nuts. Didn't matter what device I used as the source.
I was just able to update the firmware using the official Bose app and that seems to have fixed it! Yay.

1.0.6 to 1.5.1

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bose.monet

[image]
[image]

Comment: Although some updates have made the problems worse so check Bose forums first